# Display an image briefly - Android

Tags: android, image

I am looking for a way to display an image briefly on the Android device screen.
All i found for now is to instance an `ImageView` on a `layout`, then clear it, but i was wondering if there were other ways to do it.

**For the text, the `Toast` permits that, and something similar for a picture would be exactly what i am looking for.**

Comment: `but i was wondering if there were other ways to do it.` there's _usually_ various different ways to achieve things, you have to tell us specifically what you've tried, what you want to achieve and what isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved simply by using [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable) as follows:

```java
private ImageView imgView;
private final int interval = 1000; // 1 Second
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        if (imgView != null) {
            imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    imgView = findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    flashImage();

}
private void flashImage() {
    imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
}
```

The `postDelayed` method will hide the imageView after 1s. You can customize it as you want.